# Google Site Verification via API Key

Tags: api, oauth, google-search-console, google-api-ruby-client, google-site-verification-api

We have tried various things to get the Google Site Verification API to work, including:
[How can I authorize with OAuth 2.0 for google's predictive API in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391685/how-can-i-authorize-with-oauth-2-0-for-googles-predictive-api-in-ruby/15484612#15484612)

By calling: `https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/webResource/list` using the service account we always get an empty response: `{}`

When trying the same thing via the web console we get all the websites. We have like 30 websites.

I also had a look at this stackoverflow: [Unable to access Google Sites via API, but can via Oauth Playground. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690140/unable-to-access-google-sites-via-api-but-can-via-oauth-playground-why), without success.

- Why is the body empty?

OAuth 2.0 is not an option for us, as we have a server application.

Comment: "OAUTH2 is not an option for us, as we have a server application." -- there is a service account flow in OAuth 2.0 for use on servers, where you use a private key sitting on the server instead of a user authentication workflow.  See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the service account, it will only list the sites that are owned by that service account. If you want to get the sites of a specific user, you must impersonate that user.

I haven't implemented it yet, but apparently you must go to `http://www.google.com/a/{your-domain}/ManageOauthClients` logged as the user that owns the sites and authorize the client ID of the service account you'll use to access the API, with the appropriate scopes.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iK14bfd6qhs) explains it using Google Drive, but the authentication process is the same.

I'm not sure if this is available for Gmail users.

Comment: The problem is we do not have a Google Apps account. I tested the way you mentioned with a newly created apps account and it works. Is there any way to get this to work with a plain gmail account?